# Inverse the angular checkbox default values

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I need to inverse the default values of checkbox. For eg. if checkbox is checked it sends the value as boolean true but i want to send value as false and vice versa.

Also if i assign the value as false in angular reactive form initialization the checkbox should be in checked state and if i assign true, checkbox should not be checked. I cannot figure out any solution, any help would mean a lot. Thanks.

Here is the code I am working on

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="featureForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">

   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="featured" id="featured">
   <label for="featured" id="check1"> Checkbox 1</label><br>

   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="addons" id="addons">
   <label for="addons" id="check2"> Checkbox 2</label><br><br>

   <button>Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

component.ts file

```
featureForm:FormGroup
this.featureForm=this.fb.group({
    featured:[false,Validators.required],
    addons:[false,Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: Despite the fact that this can turn into issue in the future, can't you just use negation operator? `<input [checked]="!featured">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some like

Imagine you has a variable "variable". You can have a checkbox using ngModel like

```
<input type="checkbox" 
[ngModel]="!variable"
(ngModelChange)="variable=!$event"
>
```

See that is checked when "variable" is false and when you check/uncheck, the variable get the value false/true.

Instead use "variable" you can use the FormControl. Remember that to get the value of the FormControl you use the property `.value` and to give value to the FormControl you use `.setValue`. You need indicate also to Angular that your're using the ngModel in standalone way

```
<input type="checkbox" 
[ngModel]="!featureForm.get('addons').value"
(ngModelChange)="featureForm.get('addons').setValue(!$event)
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your case.

When working with Forms API (be it template driven or reactive) you need to provide explicit code to handle your form values exactly as you want them applied. The API cannot invert the booleans for you, just like it cannot adjust strings or numbers. There is no magic function to do that.

So you would take the values (from store, from api, whatever) and invert them like so:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.api.getDefaultFormValues().subscribe(({ featured, addons }) => {
    this.featureForm.setValue({   // or patchValue()
      featured: !featured,
      addons: !addons,
    })
  })
}
```

Similarly, when dispatching values outside, you would have to invert them by yourself.

Not sure why you would do that in the first place, but I assume you have a really good cause. :)

A note about the validators, for checkboxes you would rather use `Validators.requiredTrue`. And by the way, there is no such thing as `Validators.requiredFalse` in Angular (which is kind of proof that inverting the values is not something api wants to do), but you can of course write your own custom validator that makes sure the checkbox is not checked.